# How to set scroll position from view model with caliburn.micro?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a `ListBox` in my view, bound to a collection that is dynamically growing. I would like the scroll position to follow the last added item (which is appended to the bottom of the list). How can I achieve this with Caliburn.Micro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative could be to use the event aggregator to publish a message to the view.

Something like:

```
Aggregator.Publish(ItemAddedMessage<SomeItemType>(itemThatWasJustAdded));
```

and in the view:

```
public class SomeView : IHandle<ItemAddedMessage<SomeItemType>>
{

   public void Handle(ItemAddedMessage<SomeItemType> message)
   {
       // Implement view specific behaviour here
   }
}
```

It depends on what your requirements are but at least then the view is responsible for display concerns and you can still test the VM

Also you could just implement the code solely in the view - since it appears to be a view concern (e.g. using the events that listbox provides)

A behaviour would also be useful but maybe one that's a little less coupled to your types - e.g. a generic behaviour `SeekAddedItemBehaviour` which hooks listbox events to find the last item. Not sure if the listbox exposes the required events, but worth a look

EDIT:

Ok this may work full stop - you should be able to just attach this behaviour to the listbox and it should take care of the rest:

```
public class ListBoxSeekLastItemBehaviour : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<ListBox>
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceWatcherProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSourceWatcher", typeof(object), typeof(ListBoxSeekLastItemBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged));

    private ListBox _listBox = null;

    private static void OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxSeekLastItemBehaviour source = d as ListBoxSeekLastItemBehaviour;

        if (source != null)
            source.OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged();
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged()
    {
        // The itemssource has changed, check if it raises collection changed notifications
        if (_listBox.ItemsSource is INotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            // if it does, hook the CollectionChanged event so we can respond to items being added
            (_listBox.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ListBoxSeekLastItemBehaviour_CollectionChanged);
        }
    }

    void ListBoxSeekLastItemBehaviour_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            // If an item was added seek it
            ScrollIntoView(e.NewItems[0]);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        // We've been attached - get the associated listbox
        var box = this.AssociatedObject as ListBox;

        if (box != null)
        {
            // Hold a ref
            _listBox = box;

            // Set a binding to watch for property changes
            System.Windows.Data.Binding binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("ItemsSource") { Source = _listBox; }  

            // EDIT: Potential bugfix - you probably want to check the itemssource here just 
            // in case the behaviour is applied after the original ItemsSource binding has been evaluated - otherwise you might miss the change
            OnItemsSourceWatcherPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void ScrollIntoView(object target)
    {
        // Set selected item and try and scroll it into view
        _listBox.SelectedItem = target;
        _listBox.ScrollIntoView(target);
    }
}
```

You probably want to tidy it up a bit and also make sure that the event handler for `CollectionChanged` is removed when the `ItemsSource` changes.

Also you might want to call it `SeekLastAddedItemBehaviour` or `SeekLastAddedItemBehavior` - I tend to keep the US spelling since it matches Microsoft's spelling. I think `SeekLastItem` sounds like it will scroll to the last item in the list rather than the last added item

Comment: Just having a look and it doesn't seem that `ListBox` is aware of an `ItemsSource` change (in Silverlight anyway) so it might not be possible to write a generic behaviour. There's a `ScrollIntoView` method that takes an object - setting the `SelectedItem` and calling `ScrollIntoView` would probably do it, but hooking the list changed events without knowing when the `ItemsSource` changes would be difficult!

Comment: Well someone managed to get round it by creating a binding to watch the property for changes - I've stuck an implementation of a behaviour in there. It should work but I've not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You could reference the view in the view model using GetView().  That also couples the view and view model.

```
var myView = GetView() as MyView;
myView.MyListBox.DoStuff
```

Another option is to create a behavior.  [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120474/Programmatic-Silverlight-Tree-View-Control-Node-Ex) is an example of how to use a behavior to expand a `TreeView` from the view model.  The same could be applied to a `ListBox`.

Comment: It's not often a good idea to have the ViewModel manipulate the View - how would you separate unit testing for "just" the ViewModel? The *best* answer is to create a behavior as Derek points out. - The behavior is maintained in the View, which keeps the display concerns at the right layer.

Comment: I agree, that's why I generally use a behavior or implement an IResult but nevertheless referencing the view from the vm is an option.  It's a handy quick and dirty way to do a proof of concept that later can be moved to a more decoupled option.

Comment: I mentioned an IResult in my previous comment, it won't work in this particular case so I didn't include it in the answer.  IResult's are handy in some cases because of the ActionExecutionContext that is passed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an easier way to achieve this, without any of the above.

Just extend your Listbox with the following:

```
namespace Extensions.Examples {
    public class ScrollingListBox : ListBox
        {
            protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.NewItems != null)
                {
                    int newItemCount = e.NewItems.Count;
                    if (newItemCount > 0)
                        this.ScrollIntoView(e.NewItems[newItemCount - 1]);

                    base.OnItemsChanged(e);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Then in Xaml, Declare the Location of your extension class as so:

```
xmlns:Extensions="clr-namespace:Extensions.Examples"
```

And when you create your listbox, instead of using

```
<Listbox></Listbox>
```

Just use your extended class

```
<Extensions:ScrollingListBox></Extensions:ScrollingListBox>
```